# Can't insert diary block entries

Tags: diary

I am having problem with inserting diary block entries into my calendar. In the [homepage](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Special-Diary-Entries.html#Special-Diary-Entries) i read that `i b` starts a block entry, pressing `i b` on the calendar mode however i see `No mark set in this buffer` in the echo erea. I also tried `M-x` and then `diary-insert-block-entry` in the calendar mode, got the same error.
Can anyone help?

Comment: The manual https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Special-Diary-Entries.html#Special-Diary-Entries says that `i b` is for "*Add a block diary entry for the current region `(diary-insert-block-entry)`.*"  Did you select a region beforehand?

Comment: @lawlist How can i select a region inside of calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc-string for `diary-insert-block-entry` is insufficient (even for an intermediate Emacs user such as myself) and I needed to actually visit the code with `M-x find-function` to see what was going on.  I initially tried selecting a region with shift-arrow, but that didn't work.  Then, I tried selecting a region with a mouse in all different shapes and forms, and none of those worked.  Finally, I came up with this three-step approach:

1. Place the cursor on the beginning date and press `C-SPC` to set the mark.
2. With the arrow key, move to the ending date.
3. Press: `i b`